# Why w-2 is given in the year of sale?

Tags: united-states, form-w-2

I got some stocks through my employer in 2015. I sold some in 2019. Why did I receive W-2 income in 2019 from my company which I no longer work? As far as I understand, either its RSU or ESPP, employer reports w-2 income in the year its given. My current employer does this.

Comment: Have you asked your former employer what the income on the W-2 was for?

Comment: No. Will ask. But based on my experience they are very lazy in responding. Most probably may not respond :-(

Comment: When did you last work for them (month and year)? Did they in 2019 payout any vacation/sick balances?

Comment: March 2016. I did not get any pay from them after 2016. I got a w-2 now because of my stock sales in 2019.(1099-B also shows this w-2 amount that they reported).

Comment: Any chance they were stock options, or somehow these stocks didn't vest until last year?

Comment: No, they are ESPP